# Modular function for upper triangular matrices from Iwaniec

Tags: number-theory, topological-groups, haar-measure

In Section 1.2 of Iwaniec's *Spectral Methods of Automorphic Forms*, there is a description of Haar measures and modular functions. There is a point where he deduces the modular function for the group of upper triangular matrices; I know how this is done separately, but I don't follow his logic in the book.

First, let me give a few definitions and context from the book. I extract parts from pages 14-15.

If $G$ is a locally compact group, $G$ has a left-invariant Haar measure. This Haar measure is unique up to positive constant multiple. If $\mu$ is the Haar measure, we can define another Haar measure $\mu'$ by $\mu'(S) = \mu(Sh^{-1})$ for any measurable set $S$ and $h \in G$. As $\mu'$ is also left-invariant, we must have that
$$ \delta(h) \int_G f(g) d\mu = \int_G f(g) d \mu' = \int_G f(gh) d \mu$$
for some $\delta(h) > 0$. Actually, $\delta: G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ is a continuous group homomorphism, and we call it the *modular function* of $G$.

Let $A$ and $N$ denote the positive diagonal matrices and unipotent groups,
$$ A = \left\{ a(y) = \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{y} & \\ & 1/\sqrt{y} \end{pmatrix} : y > 0\right\}$$
and
$$ N = \left\{ n(x) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & x \\ & 1 \end{pmatrix} : x \in \mathbb{R} \right\}.$$
Both $A$ and $N$ are abelian, and thus unimodular (i.e. their left and right Haar measures coincide, or equivalently their modular functions are trivial). In the coordinates above, their Haar measures are $dn = dx$ and $da = y^{-1} dy$.

Let $P = AN$. Iwaniec defines the Haar measure $dp = da dn = y^{-1} dy dx$ on $P$ through
$$ \int_P f(p) dp = \int_A \int_N f(an) \, da \, dn.$$
A short computation (essentially noting that $a(y)n(x) = n(xy)a(y)$ and changing variables) shows that $dp$ is left-invariant.

Now we get to the part that I don't follow. By Fubini's theorem, we have that
$$\begin{align}
\int_A \int_N f(a(y)n(x)) \frac{dx \, dy}{y}
&= \int_N \int_A f(n(xy)a(y)) \frac{dx \, dy}{y} \\
&= \int_N \int_A f(n(x)a(y)) \frac{dx \, dy}{y^2}.
\end{align}$$
**This shows that the modular function of $P$ is $\delta(p) = y^{-1}$ if $p = a(y)n(x)$.**

> Why does it follow that the modular function of $P$ is $\delta(p) = y^{-1}$ in these coordinates?

Comment: Perhaps $
\int_P f(p) dp=\int_A \int_N f(a(y)n(x)) \frac{dx \, dy}{y}=\int_N \int_A f(n(x)a(y)) \frac{dx \, dy}{y^2}$ gives that you can easily compute $\int_P f(p\ n(-u)a(\frac1v)) dp=\int_P f(p\ a(\frac1v)) dp=v\int_P f(p)dp $ and thus $v^{-1}=\frac1{\delta(n(-u)a(\frac1v))}=\delta(a(v) n(u))$.

Comment: I would have directly written $\int_P f(pp_0)dp$ and derived $y_0^{-1}\int_P f(p)dp$, essentially by the same computations you quote. Maybe reuns got the right idea to interpret what Iwaniec was meaning. Here is how I understand it: when multiplying by $p_0 = n(x_0) a(y_0)$ on the right, you can absorb $n(x_0)$ by the LHS form, at no cost, and absord $a(y_0)$ by the RHS form, at a cost $y_0^{-1}$, which thus is $\delta(p_0)$. Could it be how Iwaniec derives his conclusion right after this equality?